# Single DAO for webservice and database

Tags: java, spring-mvc, design-patterns, dao

I am writing my first Spring MVC webapp and have a question about DAOs and web service requests.

Essentially my app allows the user to construct an order, which gets persisted to a database via a DAO. Later on a scheduled worker will retrieve the new orders from the database, submit them to a third-party SOAP service and update each order with some details (e.g. order number).

My controller calls the OrderService (a condensed version):

```
@Service
public class OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private OrderDao orderDao;

    public List<Order> getOrderList() {

        List<Order> orders = orderDao.getAllOrders();

        return orders;
    }

    public void addNewOrder(Order order) {

        orderDao.addOrder(order);
    }
}
```

The OrderService calls the OrderDao:

```
@Repository
public class OrderDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    @Autowired
    public OrderDao(DataSource dataSource) {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    public List<Order> getAllOrders() {

        String sqlQuery = "SELECT id, name, status, orderNumber FROM orders";

        List<Order> orders = getJdbcTemplate().query(sqlQuery, new OrderRowMapper());

        return orders;

    }

    public int addOrder(Order order) {

        String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO orders (name, status) VALUES (?, ?)";

        getJdbcTemplate().update(sqlQuery, new Object[] { order.getName(), order.getStatus() });

        return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", Integer.class );
    }
}
```

The Order model looks like:

```
public class Order {

    private int orderId;
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private String orderNumber;

    // getters and setters etc.
}
```

At present my OrderDao only communicates with the database to perform CRUD actions on the Order model. I am not sure whether I should create a placeOrder() method within the OrderDao as this would mean I have a single DAO that accesses both database and SOAP service, which feels wrong.

It also feels wrong to put placeOrder() in the OrderService because the service will contain a mixture of internal DAO calls and external third-party SOAP calls.

I've been reading up on interfaces but I don't think they help me here as my database DAO would contain create(), update(), delete() which wouldn't apply to a SOAP DAO.

Should I just create two DAOs: OrderDaoDatabase and OrderDaoSoap?

Comment: Is your `placeOrder()` same as `addOrder()`? Can't find it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of using layered architecture is to encourage decoupling and separation of concerns. You already have the service layer to take care of business logic and data access layer (DAOs) to communicate with the database, that seems to be right. OrderService should talk to the database and OrderDAO should talk to the database.

Your scheduled worker seems to be a different class. OrderDAO can expose the order(s) data through different methods (which are required by your application). If `placeOrder()` is a call to external web service, it's okay to call that from an appropriate method within OrderService or a different class if required. Now, since that call isn't done at the time `addOrder()` is called, it probably belongs to a different method which is invoked by the scheduler. On the other hand, I don't think `placeOrder()` should go into `OrderDAO`, it should be left for what it says - data access object.